# What data structure or iterative methods to be used to get circular list behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, data-structures

Say I have a collection [1,2,3,4] I would like to iterate from 1st element to last element and then back to first element. so it should be 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2.... till some thing is true.

currently I am thinking of

```
while(IsSomethingTrue)
{
    for(var i=0;i<Myarr.length;i++)
    {
       //do-something
       if(i==(Myarr.length-1)) 
       {
            i=0; //setting it back to first index
       }
    }
}
```

I know this is a elementary question and above is one way I could achieve the goal but was wondering is there any better way like a data structure along the lines of circular list or any looping methods in javascript that could go on iterating till the end of array and start from beginning again.

For those why i need this is: I am trying to visualize Dining philosophers in Javascript and need this kind of a behavior to happen.

Comment: Nope.. your logic is correct. This is the right way to do this. There is no internal native way to loop back as you have described.

Comment: Please improve the title so that others who need to solve the same problem can find this question.

Comment: You can achieve the effect using `i = (i + 1) % Myarr.length`. It's not quite readable though.

Comment: @RaymondChen I edited the title, If it still not clear please go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Define `Myarr.length` as a variable outside the `while` loop for better performance.

Comment: Your logic is _not_ correct: `i` will never be equal to `Myarr.length` inside the loop shown, so the `if` test will never be true. But you can remove that `if` completely since when the `for` ends it'll just do another iteration of the `while` (if that condition is still true) and start the `for` again. If you try to adjust `i` back to 0 as part of the `for` loop itself the `for` loop will never end.

Comment: Note that I edited my previous comment with a little more info on why adjusting `i` inside the `for` loop is incorrect even with your edit. Fortunately you just don't need that bit at all.

Comment: @Mojtaba Unless you're checking the length of a NodeList (and _not_ a JavaScript array) that statement isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

While the performance will be decreased, if you just wanted shorter code, and if you don't mind mutating the Array, you could do this:

```
while(IsSomethingTrue)
{
    var item = Myarr[0];
    // do something with item
    Myarr.push(Myarr.shift());
}
```

Again, to be clear, there will most certainly be some performance impact. Just thought I'd show it as a possibility.

You could also shallow clone the Array using `.slice()` before entering the `while` loop if you don't want to mutate the original.

Comment: Or: `var item = Myarr.shift(); /* do something with item */ Myarr.push(item);`

Comment: @Bergi: That makes more sense.

Comment: Not necessarily, it for example changes `Myarr.length` during the `doing something with item`. It just might be more descriptive if you only need the `item` (but then the modulo thing is easier) - if you need the whole mutated array each loop turn, then yours is better.

Comment: It is a bad practice to sacrifice readability and performance just to make a program's source code shorter.  If a person is concerned with the amount of code, then they should use **modularity** to address it.  If the program is already sufficiently modularized, then the code should be as long as it needs to be, taking **readability** and **efficiency** into account.

Comment: @Sildoreth: Readability is subjective. This seems simple enough to quickly comprehend what it does. But WRT performance, I gave ample warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you stated is efficient and readable enough. A single if-statement is not very costly.

Another solution is to use a circular linked list. But I don't think that would gain you anything unless you will be inserting elements into the data structure.

Comment: What's a "circular linked list"? Some object with a `next()` method and the internal structure that he already uses?

Comment: A circular linked list is a linked list where the node that would otherwise be the last node points to the first node as its next node. Therefore, when you loop over the list by continually going to the next node, it forms a circle and you end up where you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, but you can save a few characters-

```
var a= Myarr, L= a.length, i= 0;
while(i<L){
    //do-something with a[i]
    if(++i== L) i= 0; // increment or reset
}
```

Comment: The `isSomethingTrue` condition in the OPs code is for sure not `i<L`, as that would create an infinite loop…

Comment: You can break out of the loop or return a value in the do-something bit.